# alert not working before re-direction asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, alert, response.redirect

In my asp.net web application, i am trying to do a simple operation.
1. bring up an alert "saved successfull" using Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock from my code behind. This seems to work fine.
2. After the message, when I try to add a response.redirect to a different page, the above alert fails. redirection does happen but with out the alert.

I have tested by script separately and it works fine. The only issue is, if I do a redirect, redirect happens with out alert.

I tried to move the alert from code behind to jquery ( calling a jquery function that first alerts and does a window.location.href. But this also does not work.

Is it because my redirection is faster than time taken for the alert to come up? How can i solve this issue? Any out of the box ideas are welcome.

Comment: Code? is your alert before or after the redirect?

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), "myscript", "alert('test');window.location.href='Help.aspx'", true);

Comment: redirect after alert.both on client side( from registerClientScriptBlock). both happen independent of each other properly)

Comment: Are you getting any JS error, for not showing up alert and instead redirects.

Comment: no..nothing at all. If I remove redirect alert functions well. Add redirect and it gets redirected but with out the alert. a real annoying issue i Say...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function DisplayAlertAndRedirect() {
            alert("Save Successful");
            location.href = "/Default2.aspx";
        }
    </script>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save And Redirect" OnClick="btnSave_Click"/>
```

and in your code-behind:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(typeof (Page), "SaveAndRedirect"))
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof (Page), "SaveAndRedirect", "DisplayAlertAndRedirect();", true);
    }
}
```

Just tested this and it works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks. works..i did not nothing different in my piece of code except mau be I should not have used registerclientScriptBlock and should have gone with RegisterStartupScripy. Thanks a ton.